# Error when making API call to Google

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using this OAuth library in Google Apps script https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/Smartsheet.gs

and trying to make a call to Google Site Verification API, however I get following error while doing it-:

Request failed for https://www.googleapis.com/siteVerification/v1/token returned code 500. Truncated server response: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"backendError","message":"Backend Error"}],"code":500,"message":"Backend Error"}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 14, file "Service")

```
function run() {
  var service = getiService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {

    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/siteVerification/v1/token';

    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      'headers': {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
      },
      'method': 'GET',

  "site": {
    "identifier": "somedomainname.com",
    "type": "INET_DOMAIN"
  },
  "verificationMethod": "DNS_TXT"

                                   });

 Logger.log(result)
```

Your help is appreciated.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my environment, [the OAuth library that you say](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/Smartsheet.gs) couldn't be used. So I retrieved access token and refresh token by myself and confirmed that this script works. If the library also cannot be used at your environment, please retrieve access token and refresh token.

If you want to get a verification token using the endpoint of `https://www.googleapis.com/siteVerification/v1/token`, you can see the reference [`WebResource: getToken`](https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/webResource/getToken). According to the reference, the method is "post". And at [`UrlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#getRequest(String,Object)), it writes the request body to `payload`. When these are reflected to the script, the script becomes as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/siteVerification/v1/token';
var requestBody = {
  site: {
    identifier: "somedomainname.com",
    type: "INET_DOMAIN",
  },
  verificationMethod: "DNS_TXT",
};
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()}, // In my environment, service.getAccessToken() was changed to access token I retrieved.
  method: 'post',
  payload: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
});
```

#### Result :

```
{
  "method": "DNS_TXT",
  "token": "google-site-verification=#####"
}
```

Comment: @Gela Ram Welcome. Thank you, too.

Comment: As a next step, now i need to to call Insert, which requires verificationMethod parameter, can you help telling me how would i incorporate this parameters?
thank you

https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/webResource/insert